# ¿Como puedo añadir cabeceras en un response?

Tags: angular7

**/_request/httpClient.ts**

Es donde añado las cabeceras, este archivo añade mas funcionalidad a HttpClient de angular, es necesario para autenticación.

```html
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class HttpClientInterno {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  createAuthorizationHeader(headers: HttpHeaders) {
    if (localStorage.getItem('authentication')==null){
      localStorage.setItem('authentication', Math.random()+'');
    }
    headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' +
      btoa('username:password'+localStorage.getItem('authentication'))); 
    console.log(headers.get('Authorization'));
  }
  
...

  post(url, data) {
    debugger;
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    this.createAuthorizationHeader(headers);
    return this.http.post(url, data, { headers: headers });
  }
...
}
```

**/_services/autentication.service.ts**

Es el servicio que lo utiliza, como se puede ver es la autenticación que va contra una api java.

```html
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import {HttpClientInterno} from '../_request/HttpClient';

// rxjs
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

/**
 * AutorizacionService class. Servicio de autorizaciÃ³n.
 * @author Carlos Guerra
 */
@Injectable()
export class AutorizacionService {
  static readonly CLASE:string            = 'AutorizacionService';
  static readonly URLAUTENTICATION:string = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/Daoiz/autenticacion';
  static readonly URLSERVICIO:string      = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/Daoiz/service';
  
  /**
   * Constructor.
   * @param http     Para conectarse con el api.
   */
 constructor (protected http: HttpClientInterno) {
  }
   /**
   * Login de usuario.
   * @param login     Usuario, en este caso el correo.
   * @param password  ContraseÃ±a.
   * @returns Usuario logado o anonimo
   */
  public login(login, password): Observable<any> {
    console.log(AutorizacionService.CLASE + '.login: entra');
    
    let body:any = {
        'service':'getLogin',
        'params': {
         'login':login,
         'password':password
        }
      };
    console.log(AutorizacionService.CLASE + '.login: sale');
    return this.http.post( AutorizacionService.URLAUTENTICATION,  body );
  }
...

}
```

El problema es que las cabeceras nunca se llegan a añadir, ¿No se pueden enviar cabeceras?, lo he debugueado y nunca se llegan a añadir.

El resultado es una map vacia, despues de añadir con APPEND

Answer (score 1):

Como se puede ver en la documentación oficial [objeto HttpHeaders de Angular es inmutable](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpHeaders#httpheaders):

> Instances are immutable. Modifying methods return a cloned instance
>   with the change. The original object is never changed.

Cada vez que añades un header se crea un objeto nuevo, por tanto la forma de usarlo es:

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers = headers.append('header1','value1');
headers = headers.append('header2','value2');
...
```

Pero se puede encadenar así para ahorrar asignaciones:

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders()
  .append('header1','value1')
  ... //adjuntando los que necesites añadir ...
  .append('headerN','valueN');

//para headers que son condicionales
if (condicion) {
  headers = headers.append('...','...');
}
```

Comment: no esta resuelto, la respuesta es erronea

Comment: @CarlosGuerraCubillo No entiendo qué quieres decir con tus comentarios

Answer (score 0):

El codigo quedaria asi, creo la cabecera dentro y la devuelvo

**/_request/httpClient.ts**

```html
            

import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class HttpClientInterno {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  createAuthorizationHeader(): HttpHeaders {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    if (localStorage.getItem('authentication')==null){
      localStorage.setItem('authentication', Math.random()+'');
    }
    headers = headers.append('content-Type','application/json');
    headers = headers.append('authorization', 'Basic ' +
      btoa('username:password' + localStorage.getItem('authentication'))); 
    return headers;
  }
  createAuthorizationHeaderMultipart():HttpHeaders {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    if (localStorage.getItem('authentication')==null){
      localStorage.setItem('authentication', Math.random()+'');
    }
    headers = headers.append('content-Type', 'multipart/form-data; boundary=MultipartBoundry');
    headers = headers.append('authorization', 'Basic ' +
      btoa('username:password' + localStorage.getItem('authentication'))); 
    return headers;
  }
  get(url) {
    let headers = this.createAuthorizationHeader();
    return this.http.get(url, {
      headers: headers
    });
  }

  post(url, data) {
    let headers = this.createAuthorizationHeader();
    return this.http.post(url, data, { headers: headers });
  }
  postUp(url, data) {
    let headers = this.createAuthorizationHeaderMultipart();
    return this.http.post(url, data, { headers: headers });
  }
}
```

Esto si funciona, ya se añaden las cabeceras